# Is it possible to merge this two Task Scheduler - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to merge this two schedule to one single schedule. First Schedule runs for 17 mins everyday from 10:29 am to 10:45 pm. And second one runs for 17 mins between 14:59 pm to 15:15 pm everyday. Each of them run every minute. Same time zone and same command.

Can I have something like 2 between? What is the elegant way to do this?

```
 $schedule->command('abcd')->timezone('john_doe')->between('10:29', '10:45')->everyMinute();
 $schedule->command('abcd')->timezone('john_doe')->between('14:59', '15:15')->everyMinute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `->when(Closure)`

```
$schedule->command('abcd')->timezone('john_doe')->everyMinute()->when(function () {
    $now = Carbon::now()->getTimestamp();

    return ($now >= strtotime('10:29') && $now <= strtotime('10:45'))
        || ($now >= strtotime('14:59') && $now <= strtotime('15:15'));
});
```